# Why are the two queries different (left join on ... and ... as opposed to using where clause)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm wondering why the following two queries produce different results (the first query has more rows than second).

```
SELECT * FROM A
  JOIN ...
  JOIN ...
  JOIN C ON ...
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id AND B.otherId = C.otherId
```

As opposed to:

```
SELECT * FROM A
  JOIN ...
  JOIN ...
  JOIN C ON ...
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.id = A.id
WHERE B.otherId = C.otherId
```

Please help me understand. In the second query, the left join has only 1 condition so shouldn't it include all the results from the first query and more (where the extra rows have unmatched `otherId`). Then the `WHERE` clause should ensure that the `otherId` matches, like in the first query. Why are they different?

Comment: The `WHERE` is performed first by the Query engine before performing the `JOIN`. The reasoning being why do the JOIN, if we are going to filter some rows later. The query engines are pretty good at optimizing the query you write.

Comment: The `Where` clause you're using effectively changes your `Outer Join` into an `Inner Join`.  The first would include records that didn't have the `otherId` matching as `Null`, but the second would discard them in the `Where` filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WHERE` is performed first by the Query engine before performing the `JOIN`.
The reasoning being why do the expensive `JOIN`, if we are going to filter some rows later. 
The query engines are pretty good at optimizing the query you write.

Also you will see this effect only in `OUTER JOIN`s. In inner joins both `WHERE` and `JOIN` conditions behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

The second query returns less rows because your `where` clause was filtering the records out, and this is essentially changing the query from a left outer join to an inner join.  So, you need to be careful where you place your filters in, but this will not matter if you were to do an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You've received correct answers, but allow me to delve a little deeper into the difference between join criteria and filtering criteria. Take a simple query with a left join:

```
select a.Key, a.NonKey1, b.NonKey2
from a
left join b on b.Key = a.Key;
```

This lists out all of `NonKey1` values from table `a` and any `NonKey2` fields from table `b` with matching key values or `NULL` where there is no match. A common variant is to look at only those rows in `a` that do not have a match in `b`:

```
select a.Key, a.NonKey1, b.NonKey2
from a
left join b on b.Key = a.Key
where b.Key is null;
```

Careful! If you accidentally write `where b.Key is not null` you've just changed your outer join into a regular inner join. Do that sometime and see if QA can catch it. On second thought, don't. (Also, having `b.NonKey2` in the selection list is meaningless as it can only ever be `NULL`, but let's leave it there for the moment.) The join is based on the key fields of both tables matching. After the joining is complete, all rows with a successful join are discarded and only the results without a match remain. That means `b.Key` in the join criteria *cannot* be `NULL` and in the filtering criteria *must* be `NULL` for a row to be added to the result set. Fine, that's what we wanted. But consider what would happen if we moved the check to become part of the join criteria.

```
select a.Key, a.NonKey1, b.NonKey2
from a
left join b on b.Key = a.Key and b.Key is null;
```

The result is everything from `a` with nothing at all from `b`. Probably not what we wanted. If you think about it, you will see we could just as well have written `on 0 = 1` and gotten the same result. What we've done is move a value from one context where `NULL` means one thing (success) to a context where `NULL` means something entirely different (failure).

So, in computer languages as in human languages, be careful of context. It can completely change the meaning of what you're trying to say.